# Shakespeare. William Shakespeare

Tags: movies, poetry, literature

Can you determine these popular quotes as retold by Shakespeare? Before anyone points out, yes I'm aware that Bill used predominantly iambic pentameter, but I've never been a huge fan of that, so I'm going with iambic tetrameter instead.

1.

> How oft the potion, orange in hue
>   delights my sense among the dew.

2.

> Indeed this land can scarce contain
>   Our presence should we both remain.

3.

> From first I heard thine mouth's sweet spell
>   A victim helpless I befell.

4.

> This vessel shall contain our dirge
>   Should storm or monstrous beast resurge.

5.

> His stature lacking to impress
>   Beseech you greet him none the less.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, one of the most sincere entries for the [topic challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-movies?cb=1) yet. We both know I prefer fun-loving rhyme to a simply inscrutable cryptogram. +1, Excellent work, my twin!

Comment: @Roland thanks for the compliment and I'm glad you enjoyed it!

Comment: Wouldn't #4 be better phrased as "this vessel shan't contain..."

Comment: @Octopus Can you explain your reasoning? Changing it to "shan't" implies to me that there will be no deaths to mourn, no dirge. That would correspond to a quote like "This boat is plenty big and safe, should the shark attack".

Comment: Well assuming that "dirge" is symbolic of the shark, the shark cannot be contained by the current boat as it is too small. But I see your point and I do think it could be interpretted either way, now. The quote as it sits did at first remind me of Jaws but it also seems to state the opposite from the Movie's quote.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a shot. All but the 2nd are on [this nifty Wikilist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFI%27s_100_Years...100_Movie_Quotes):

How oft the potion, orange in hue
delights my sense among the dew.

> "I love the smell of napalm in the morning." -- *Apocalypse Now*

Indeed this land can scarce contain
Our presence should we both remain.

> "This town ain't big enough for the both of us", -- [*The Western Code*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023682/quotes) My thanks to dperry!

From first I heard thine mouth's sweet spell
A victim helpless I befell.

> "You had me at 'hello.'" -- *Jerry Maguire*

This vessel shall contain our dirge
Should storm or monstrous beast resurge.

> "You're gonna need a bigger boat." -- *Jaws*

His stature lacking to impress
Beseech you greet him none the less.

> "Say 'hello' to my little friend!" -- *Scarface*

And for flavor, the title references...

> "Bond. James Bond" -- first said in *Dr. No*

Comment: #2 is "This town ain't big enough for the both of us", originally from The Western Code

Comment: Thank you! Apparently that quote didn't make any "Top X" lists, because I searched "town" in most of them. :)

Comment: Summarily solved! Nice work; I tried to get more that were not readily on the lists, but they're so comprehensive!

Comment: Additionally: the title is (fairly obviously) “Bond. James Bond”, just to get that in there explicitly. :-)

Comment: Lol, yeah. Guess I'll put that in the answer for those puzzling from under their rocks.

Comment: Just had to: http://imgur.com/zHPnHDe