# Art Thou Addressing Me?

Tags: movies, poetry

Yesterday's [Shakespearean quotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22206/shakespeare-william-shakespeare) went so well, I decided to give it another go. I tried to pick ones that were a tad more obscure (by which I mean featured on fewer top X lists), but all are in my opinion well known.

1.

> Do not from me applause withhold!
>   Do I not your attention hold?

2.

> 'Twere mine own loving arms were sought
>   by maid from which thou were begot

3.

> A distance never trekked before
>   I shall traverse; and one step more!

4.

> The cobbled stones we'll not desire
>   when destination we acquire.

5.

> I've just two tasks; to your dismay
>   my stash of sweets be empt this day.

6.(a bit harder than the others)

> The darkened mind alone shall call
>   the words of nary one or all

Comment: Had to make an edit to the last one; I copied a wrong version and had a messed up iamb at the start (though I'm aware that this is technically allowable)

Comment: “Doth I”? Is the lack of subject–verb agreement intentional/a clue?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet nope, just poor archaic grammar on my part

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Full set of answers, with thanks to derium:

1. > "Are you not entertained?" Maximus, *Gladiator*
2. > "I am your father" Darth Vader, *Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back*
3. > "To Infinity... And Beyond!" Buzz Lightyear, *Toy Story*
4. > "Where we're going, we don't need roads!" Doc Brown, *Back to the future*
5. > "I came here to chew bubblegum and kick ass... and I'm all out of bubblegum" Nada, *They Live*
6. > "Only a Sith deals in absolutes" a hypocritical jedi, *Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith* (shamelessly borrowed from derium)

And for the title:

> "You talkin' to me?" Travis Bickle, *Taxi Driver*

Given the theme of the puzzle, I feel obliged to point out that there is a [Shakespearean 'translation' of the original Star Wars trilogy](http://www.amazon.co.uk/William-Shakespeares-Star-Wars-Doescher/dp/1594746370)

Comment: #2 is definitely a stretch.  Not sure what movie this is from, but when I try to de-Shakespeare-ize that quote, I get a mental image of some obnoxious kid jeering "I just banged your mom!"

Comment: @MasonWheeler ha! Good point.

Comment: @MasonWheeler that's why I added loving. 'I banged your mom...with love'. Sorry if it seems like a stretch but Logician has it correct

Comment: Oh, for #2 I was thinking Paul Finch from American Pie.

Comment: #6 is less well known admittedly, but if you got #2, then there's a good chance you've heard it

Comment: #2 is hilarious!

Answer (score 7):

For 6

> Only a Sith deals in absolutes.

Comment: Of course! So simple. I’d gotten as far as S###s, but couldn’t think of anything that fit the rest. +1!

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, how about

> "I believe I deserve some recognition from this board" - *Mark Zuckerberg* from *The Social Network*